# Spring 4 MVC + HTTPS

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Could not find how to use HTTPS with Spring MVC. 
http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#spring-introduction

Could you please share any examples how to use Spring MVC with HTTPS. Or if I want to use HTTPS I should use Oauth ?

Thanks

Comment: even though [we do not all agree](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254398/do-we-need-better-guidance-for-recommendation-questions#258137), unfortunately, requests for ["a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) might help you edit your question to get better answers

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR Spring MVC has nothing that should be configured to using HTTPS because they are orthogonal. You should configure your servlet container instead (Tomcat, Jetty, etc).

If you're using Spring Security, you could add some configuration for it. Also Spring Boot has some parameters for HTTPS (because Spring Boot application runs Tomcat/Jetty/Undertow under the hood).